# Can I enable intranet users to take screenshot of the current page via the browser?

Tags: java, javascript, flash, web, screenshot

Is it possible to create a screenshot from the current page the user is on? (It's for an Intranet enviroment).

I know this is not possible with JavaScript alone, but is it possible with Flash or maybe an Java applet?

I have been searching around but I couldn't find anything.

Thanks.

Comment: It is not possible via Flash. A Flash instance can take a snapshot of itself, but not of the HTML page around it.

Comment: There's a Firefox extension that does this called [Screengrab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/screengrab/). Maybe that could help you.

Answer (score 3):

It might be possible to do in a Java applet that is signed. The Robot class has a method that makes it possible to capture the screen; [Robot.createScreenCapture](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture%28java.awt.Rectangle%29)

Comment: That only makes a screenshot of a visible portion of the screen, the website might be bigger than that. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Ah, so you don't want to have a screen shot in that case, because a screen shot is always only of that you see. You want to specify what it is that you want, and what you want the output for.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the page url to server side script or to an app on the server and return the full page screenshot image

Comment: That's probably not useful, because often you'll want user input and/or misrenderings/problems that are (not yet) reproduceable anywhere but the users machine.

Answer (score 0):

A software product like [Easy Capture](http://easycapture.en.softonic.com/) allows Windows users to take a screen shot of the full screen, which can be useful in debugging.