# Can I record the browser using Flash?

Tags: flash

Can I record the browser using Adobe Flash? something like screenr.com but only for the tab of my website, is it possible?

obviosuly i would like to record all the screen the user is seeing not only the "space" with flash.

Thank you

Comment: There's a [very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090466/can-i-enable-intranet-users-to-take-screenshot-of-the-current-page-via-the-browse) that indicates that this is not possible in Flash (probably for security reasons).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with Flash: Flash's "vision" is limited to itself. 
Screenr uses Java for this purpose.